# EPPlus merges background colors?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I am using EPPlus to fill out some data in an Excel sheet.  As part of this I'm setting the background color based on other data in my program.  This seems to be working, however the colors come out darker than what I put in.  I messed around with it and I figured out if I put them in a row that is white in the template they come out correct, but if I put them in a row that has a gray background set they come out dark.  It seems like EPPlus (or Excel) are merging the colors together...

I want the row to be gray overall but want to be able to set color overrides for specific cells in certain places.  Here is my code:

```
                Color fillColor;
                Color foreColor = Color.Black;

                if (pd.BuiltInParameter == default(int))
                {
                    fillColor = Color.Black;
                    foreColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (pd.ParameterRevitType)
                    {
                        case "Text":
                            fillColor = Color.FromArgb(198, 89, 17);
                            break;
                        case "URL":
                            fillColor = Color.FromArgb(68, 114, 196);
                            break;
                        case "Length":
                            fillColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 153, 51);
                            break;
                        case "Material":
                            fillColor = Color.FromArgb(48, 84, 150);
                            foreColor = Color.White;
                            break;
                        case "YesNo":
                            fillColor = Color.FromArgb(112, 48, 160);
                            foreColor = Color.White;
                            break;
                        case "FamilyType":
                            fillColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0);
                            break;
                        case "Image":
                            fillColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 176, 240);
                            break;
                        case "Currency":
                            fillColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 176, 80);
                            break;
                        default:
                            fillColor = Color.Red;
                            foreColor = Color.White;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                ws.Cells[4, currentColumn].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                ws.Cells[4, currentColumn].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(fillColor);
                if (foreColor != Color.Black)
                {
                    ws.Cells[3, currentColumn].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(foreColor);
                }
```

Is there a way to make it use just the colors specified?  What am I missing here?

Here's a graphic of the color previews in VS and the colors that come out:

[image]

As a test I had it set the main row and the row below it (below it is white).  Here is the result:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Ok I have a reproducible sample.  Here is the code for a small console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
        string templatePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "Template.xlsx");
        string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "Export.xlsx");

        if (File.Exists(filePath)) File.Delete(filePath);
        File.Copy(templatePath, filePath);

        using (var ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
        {
            var ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets["Families-Types"];
            ws.Cells[3, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(150, 245, 125));
            ep.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zffnyvti9t4v0p8/Template.xlsx?dl=0) is a link to the template that it references and [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xdte1u0tmeribs/Export.xlsx?dl=0) is a link to the export I get from the program.  It almost looks correct at first, but the export is a darker green than the rgb in the program.  You can see this if you go to cell format in Excel and put in the same rgb values and press ok, it will lighten up significantly.

Comment: If you did the same thing in Excel itself (through the UI) does it look the same as what is shown in the Excel spreadsheet that you create through EPPlus?

Comment: Nope, I tried that.  If I set the fill color through Excel it just goes to that color.

Comment: Since it's XML you could open up the output, find the color, and see if it's the same as what you set.

Comment: I tried to duplicate this and I can't. `ws.Row(1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(112,48,60)); ws.Cells[1,1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0)); ws.Cells[2,1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0));`  I also set `ExcelFillStyle.Solid` for all of those ranges. So one row has its own background color, then I gave another cell in that row another background color. They didn't merge. My yellow cells are yellow.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a really simplified, minimal example that creates a workbook and sets a few colors so that we can try to replicate it. The code you posted is partial so we can't run it.

Comment: hmm.  Well I'm not setting the row through EPPlus, it's in the template I'm using so maybe there's something strange in the template or something...  Let me experiment a little more and see if I can get a minimal example.  I will also check the xml to see if it's the correct color.  Thanks for the ideas, I'll report back soon...

Comment: Posted a reproducible sample.  I tried to look through the xml but I think I did something wrong as I came up with an indexed color of 65 which if I read correctly is a system background color or something... I'm not terribly familiar with the style references, etc. that OpenXML uses...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok finally I found the issue.  I took another dive into the xml and was able to better figure it out in the simplified example.  It seems that the original color set in the template has a value for 'tint' (in this case -0.499984740745262 but it varies depending on the color).  this tint modifies the color and was carrying over to the new color for some reason.  Fortunately EPPlus has a settable property for tint.  I set it to 0 and 'ding! ding!' the colors are correct.

So here is the updated code for the working application, note the extra line after setting the color:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
        string templatePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "Template.xlsx");
        string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "Export.xlsx");

        if (File.Exists(filePath)) File.Delete(filePath);
        File.Copy(templatePath, filePath);

        using (var ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
        {
            var ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets["Families-Types"];
            ws.Cells[3, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(150, 245, 125));
            ws.Cells[3, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Tint = 0;
            ep.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps someone else.